# Resizing an image at will with CSS?

Tags: css, image, resize, height, width

I'm trying to resize a background image so that it retains 100% of height AND width of its parent element, which is a text area. I'd like the image to adjust and change aspect ratio dynamically, just like the text area. I have the following CSS, the html is just a textarea tag.

```
textarea {
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
background: url(http://gfx9.com/images/contents/b/e/beautiful-cartoon-landscapes-vector-set-14-free0.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
border-radius: 5px
```

}

With this code the image resizes horizontally, but I want it to resize both horizontally and vertically, filling all the white space in the area.

Hope someone can come up with a solution.

Comment: `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: Doesn't work with cover, the image overflows out of the area, but it does with 100% 100%. I didn't know you could specify two values for background-size. Thanks for the fast solution.

Comment: @devqon please add your suggestion as answer so that SoKeT can select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify two values, since right now it's only catching the first (which is width). Like this:

```css
div {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

You can also use `px` if you need to be specific. Additionally, there is another value called `cover` which will scale the background image to be as large as possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may not be aware that, when you have multiline code, you can display it as a code block with syntax highlighting instead of as inline code. See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for more info.